# How to use regular expression to generate short_link column in snowflake database

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to use regex to replace all user_ids in column `link`? The user_id is always started with '11'

The query should look like this:

`select link, xxxx as short_link from table`

`database: snowflake`

```
| link                                                       | short link                       |
|------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------|
| /boba/users/11EAD36BE959A83709F187596AE5966BB/styles       | /boba/users/userid/styles        |
| /boba/search                                               | /boba/search                     |
| /boba/users/11EAD36BE959A84709F187596AE5966BB/posts        | /boba/users/userid/posts         |
| /boba/users/11EAD36BE959A85709F187596AE5966BB              | /boba/users/userid               |
| /boba/users/11EAD36BE959A8709F187596AE5966BB/notifications | /boba/users/userid/notifications |
| /boba/feeds/home                                           | /boba/feeds/home                 |
| /boba/search                                               | /boba/search                     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work and provide expected output. For more information on REGEX_REPLACE please check this link.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html

```
with t as 
(
select '/boba/users/11EAD36BE959A83709F187596AE5966BB/styles' as link
union all
select '/boba/search' as link
union all
select '/boba/users/11EAD36BE959A84709F187596AE5966BB/posts' as link
union all
select '/boba/users/11EAD36BE959A85709F187596AE5966BB' as link
union all
select '/boba/users/11EAD36BE959A8709F187596AE5966BB/notifications' as link
union all
select '/boba/feeds/home' as link
union all
select '/boba/search' as link
)
select link,
REGEXP_REPLACE(link, '/11[A-Z0-9]{10,}', '/userid') AS short_link
from t;
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
SELECT
    link,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(link, '/11[A-Z0-9]{10,}', '') AS short_link
FROM yourTable;
```

This regex replacement logic would target any path component starting with `11` followed by ten or more capital letters/digits as being a user ID.